# Retrieve data from available sql server when another sql server becomes down

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I am making a project in asp.net using c# in which I am using two SQL servers. Both the servers are having the same data. I want my application to retrieve data from another server if one server goes down. Is there any method in asp.net by which we can test the server connectivity or server availability? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [Ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You're trying to implement failover on the client side. If you implement clustering at the SQL Server side then you don't have to build all the failover logic in your application.

Answer (score 3):

It is one way to do it in code.
You don't need to test for availability (what if it says "yes" and then goes down?)

What you do is to run the query, if it fails then check the error type and repeat against another server if needed.

You make one wrapping function to do it and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your using Entity Framework.

I had a similar problem testing a database connection.
I wrote this function to validate a connection string.

```
public enum DBConnectionStatus
    {
        CONNECTION_ERROR,
        AUTHENTICATION_ERROR,
        INVALID_DATABASE,
        UNKNOWN_ERROR,
        OK,
    };


  public static DBConnectionStatus ValidateConnection(string ConnectionString)
    {
        DBConnectionStatus result = DBConnectionStatus.UNKNOWN_ERROR;
        DataContext DB = new DataContext(ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            DB.Connection.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case -1:
                case 2: //Cant reach data source (not accessable or offline)
                    result = DBConnectionStatus.CONNECTION_ERROR;
                    break;
                case 4060:
                    result = DBConnectionStatus.INVALID_DATABASE;
                    break;
                case 18452:
                case 18456: //Invalid Authentication
                    result = DBConnectionStatus.AUTHENTICATION_ERROR;
                    break;
                default: //All other errors
                    result = DBConnectionStatus.UNKNOWN_ERROR;
                    break;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (DB.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                DB.Connection.Close();
            }

        }
        return result;

    }
```

You can test the connection to the primary database and if the response is CONNECTION_ERROR you can then attempt using the second.